# PDF inside iframe no back button when full screen

Tags: ios, pdf, iframe, ionic-framework

I'm developing an **ionic** app in iOS, I placed the pdf inside an iframe just by simply doing the following:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://example.com/resources/myfile.pdf" mozallowfullscreen marginwidth="2" marginheight="2" width="90%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

I didn't used **`cordovaInAppBrowser`** because I ran a lot of problem like after clicking the button the InAppBrowser doesn't open unless I don't minimize the app.   So I just used **iframe** as the workaround.  But the problem now is that, after the pdf being loaded, and the user clicks on the full screen of pdf, there's no back button.  Is there a way I can remove the full screen button from the pdf or add a back button on full screen mode of pdf? I tried removing the **mozallowfullscreen** but doesn't work since it's for the iframe not for the pdf.

P.S.
I tried accessing the **div** inside the iframe that holds the button for full screen, but no good, it doesn't get the div, it's probably because I'm violating the **Same Origin Policy**.
Here's the code on how I tried to access the div:

```
$('#myframe').each(function(){
    console.log($("div[role='toolbar']"));
});
```

Comment: Another option is using `<embed>` although I don't know if iOS supports it nor do I know if it would make any difference if it was.

Comment: hmm, i'll try using embed, thanks for the idea, but one question, will it be accepted in app store? :D is there any rules about using <embed> you know?

Comment: 1. I have no idea 2. It's a void element (no end tag) and it's purpose is to facilitate the use of plugins and external apps like Flash, PDFs, SVG, etc..

Comment: what is the value of type if it's pdf? just type="pdf" ?

Comment: ah nvm i got it "application/pdf"

Comment: hmm worked the same way as the iframe, got no luck out of this

Comment: There's one more element that deals with embeds: `<object>` and it's child element `<param>`

Comment: same functionality, hmm, i'm thinking of another possible solution, is there a way to change the target of full screen button of the pdf?

Comment: It depends on the API of the plugin, i'm not sure how Safari iOS is handled, but usually the site or app has a plugin like [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)

Comment: Have you tried the back button approach that you mentioned previously?`<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="history.back()">`